# How to type a blank password in terminal in Mac sierra

Tags: macos

I use Sudo commands  in terminal but it always asks for the password.This is annoying because I always have to set a password.So how do I type blank password in terminal in MacOS Sierra 10.12.5

Comment: I don't understand this question, nor the response you gave to Gerriet's answer. Using sudo requires an Administrator password, and that password **cannot be blank**. Plain and simple.

Answer (score 2):

sudo in macOS requires a password, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202035
So it is not about typing it, it is sudo not accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` is for executing a command with administrator privilege, so it obviously uses your administrator password which, as Monomeeth said, cannot be blank.

Having a one-letter password is highly unsecure, it is far to easily breakable.

However, if you keep the same session (eg. not closing the terminal), you won't have to type your password every time.

Answer (score 1):

**This method allows you to sudo without entering your password.**

This means you can (you should!) use a strong password to log into your mac, but can then sudo in terminal without re-entering it all the time.

you need to edit the /etc/sudoers file with the visudo command (type *sudo visudo* at the command prompt) and change the line

```
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

to

```
%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

**BEWARE:** Be sure to always "lock" your mac when you step away, anybody (who knows how..) can do wild things, with the sudo option configured like this!

Comment: Thanks but i rarely use sudo commands now.